# Unwanted space before hyphen in longtable

Tags: spacing, longtable, microtype

I have a minor typesetting problem inside the `longtable` environment.

I am writing my CV and I need to write a list of skills inside a table cell. Since I'd like to keep the document length down to one page, I am not using `itemize` to save up some space, so I have written the list manually using hyphens ("-").

I've noticed that, if the hyphen is the first character in the table cell, the first line is indented by one space, whereas if there is some text before the list everything is displayed correctly.

I've noticed that commenting out `\usepackage{microtype}` fixes the issue, but I would like to use the package because otherwise the spacing doesn't look so good.

Here's a sample of what I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,]{report}
\usepackage[swedish, italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05} 
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%----------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}}

\begin{longtable}{Rp{11cm}}
\textbf{Education}&\\
2010 - 2014 &\textbf{University and degree} 

- One course

- Another course

- Some interesting seminar\\
\textbf{Computer skills}&\\
&- Operating systems: Windows, Linux

- Other software

- Other software
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output with <code>microtype</code>]

As you can see in the picture, if there is some text before the hyphen ("University and degree") the list is displayed correctly, but the line starting with "Operating systems" is indented.

So, how do I get rid of the space before the hyphen without having to comment `microtype` out?

---

Edit: I've found out that I can fix the issue manually by adding `\hspace{-2pt}` before the indented line, but I would still like to find a proper way to do this. Thanks so far!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You shouldn't be using a hyphen in the first place, but at least an en-dash (`--`, that is, two hyphens in a row); this doesn't solve the problem, but is stylistically better.

Comment: Also `pslatex` is obsolete. Say `\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}` or `\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\\` (double backslash) at the end of each row, and inserting `&` (column separators) fixes the issue you're encountering. Incidentally, as @egreg has noted in a comment, you shouldn't be using `-`; at the very least, consider using en-dashes (created by typing `--`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[swedish, italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[vmargin=2cm,hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}}

\begin{longtable}{Rp{11cm}}
\textbf{Education}&\\
2010--2014 &\textbf{University and degree} \\
&-- One course\\
&-- Another course\\
&-- Some interesting seminar\\[1ex]
\textbf{Computer skills}\\
&-- Operating systems: Windows, Linux\\
&-- Other software\\
&-- Other software\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: I believe the result obtained above with a `longtable` environment may also be obtained with a `tabular` environment. In the example below, I typeset the material first as a `longtable` (which is centered by default) and then, after backing up and switching to a red color, with a `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[swedish, italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor} % load this package so that "tabular" env. can be typeset in red
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[vmargin=2cm,hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}}

\begin{longtable}{Rp{11cm}}
\textbf{Education}&\\
2010--2014 &\textbf{University and degree} \\
&-- One course\\
&-- Another course\\
&-- Some interesting seminar\\[1ex]
\textbf{Computer skills}\\
&-- Operating systems: Windows, Linux\\
&-- Other software\\
&-- Other software\\
\end{longtable}

\centering
\vspace{-5.46cm} % vertical adjustment, to overlayed the tabular on the longtable
\color{red}
\begin{tabular}{Rp{11cm}}
\textbf{Education}&\\
2010--2014 &\textbf{University and degree} \\
&-- One course\\
&-- Another course\\
&-- Some interesting seminar\\[1ex]
\textbf{Computer skills}\\
&-- Operating systems: Windows, Linux\\
&-- Other software\\
&-- Other software\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try this with `tabular` instead of `longtable`, you'll be surprised. ;-)

Comment: @egreg - If I use `\centering` on a `tabular` environment with the exact same contents as the `longtable` (which is already centered by default), I get the exact same look. Where's the surprise?

Comment: Check closely the position of the dashes

Comment: @egreg - I've posted an addendum, in which I overlay a `tabular` (in red) on a `longtable` (in black). I see no differences *anywhere* in the material, including the positions of the en-dashes. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `microtype` lets hyphens and dashes protrude in the margins. Let's look at a couple of examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype,longtable}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % no intercolumn space to show the problem

\begin{longtable}{l|p{3cm}}
xxx &- abc

- abc\\
\end{longtable}

\centering % longtable centers!

\begin{tabular}{l|p{3cm}}
xxx &- abc

- abc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus there is no additional space in your “Operating systems” line, but rather there is no protrusion (`longtable` does some tricks with `p` columns). The following hyphens are a bit to the left.

Solution:

```
\newcommand{\itemdash}{\mbox{\kern0pt--}}
```

I used an en-dash instead of a hyphen, which is stylistically better.

Here's the full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype,longtable}

\newcommand{\itemdash}{\mbox{\hspace{0pt}--}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % no intercolumn space to show the problem

\begin{longtable}{l|p{3cm}}
xxx &\itemdash\ abc

\itemdash\ abc\\
\end{longtable}

\centering % longtable centers!

\begin{tabular}{l|p{3cm}}
xxx &\itemdash\ abc

\itemdash\ abc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you implement `\itemdash` in your code, you'll be OK.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what microtype is doing there but you can hide it with a box and a zero space:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,]{report}
\usepackage[swedish, italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05} 
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%----------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}}

\begin{longtable}{Rp{11cm}}
\textbf{Education}&\\
2010 -- 2014 &\textbf{University and degree} 

\hskip0pt-- One course

\hskip0pt-- Another course

\hskip0pt-- Some interesting seminar\\
\textbf{Computer skills}&\\
&\hskip0pt-- Operating systems: Windows, Linux

\hskip0pt-- Other software

\hskip0pt-- Other software
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `itemize` environment, with the `wide` and `nosep` options of the `enumitem` package. I give two variants, to take into account dash protrusion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}%swedish,
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[vmargin=2cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.05}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%----------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
{\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textendash, wide =0.6em, nosep}
\begin{longtable}{R p{11cm}}
\textbf{Education}&\\
2010 - 2014 &\textbf{University and degree}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item One course
    \item Another course
    \item Some interesting seminar
    \end{itemize}\\[-\topsep]
\textbf{Computer skills}
& \leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Operating systems: Windows, Linux
    \item Other software
    \item Other software
    \end{itemize}
\end{longtable}}

{\setlist[itemize,1]{label = \,\textendash, wide, nosep}
\begin{longtable}{R p{11cm}}
\textbf{Education}&\\
2010 - 2014 &\textbf{University and degree}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item One course
    \item Another course
    \item Some interesting seminar
    \end{itemize}\\[-\topsep]
\textbf{Computer skills}
& \leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Operating systems: Windows, Linux
    \item Other software
    \item Other software
    \end{itemize}
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Bernard, thanks for your input. Is there a way to get rid of the empty line between the two sections?

Comment: @dracchio: I replaced `\\` with `\\[-\topsep]`, and slighly modified the code to have less typing. See my updated answer. Is that what you want?